# How to use threads in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I need to use a thread to perform some operations in background when my application is launched.

So having the following function, how could I run it in background?

```
-(void) performOperationInBackground{
//Call to other functions
}
```

Comment: First search read and learn. Than try yourself and than if u face problem ask here. 1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial 2.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self performOperationInBackground];
});
```

but remember that if after this operation you want update UI you must do in the Main Thread, so after that:

```
-(void) performOperationInBackground {

   //do anything in background

   //call method for update user interface in the Main Thread
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}

-(void)updateUI {

    //update user interface
}
```

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of being down voted for not specifically answering the question, for OS X and iOS development typically the use of threads is discouraged:

> Both OS X and iOS adopt a more asynchronous approach to the execution
>   of concurrent tasks than is traditionally found in thread-based
>   systems and applications. Rather than creating threads directly,
>   applications need only define specific tasks and then let the system
>   perform them. By letting the system manage the threads, applications
>   gain a level of scalability not possible with raw threads. Application
>   developers also gain a simpler and more efficient programming model.

See Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Instead of threads you will use operation queues or dispatch queues depending on the scenario.

However you do it, it's good to be consistent as Black Pixel's [performSelectorOnMainThread vs. dispatch_async](http://blackpixel.com/blog/2013/11/performselectoronmainthread-vs-dispatch-async.html) article describes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performOperationInBackground) withObject:nil];
```